# How to exclude packages when populate_sdk in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto bitbake image recipe that can be built successfully.

However, the same image recipe fails when generating SDK with `-c populate_sdk` command.

The error seems to be caused by mixing 32-bit and 64-bit versions of libraries, which is fine when building images with only binaries, but the header files collide with each other when populating the SDK root fs:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/curl-config from install of lib32-curl-dev-7.53.1-r0.cortexa7hf_neon_vfpv4 conflicts with file from package curl-dev-7.53.1-r0.aarch64
  file /usr/include/nettle/version.h from install of lib32-nettle-dev-3.3-r0.cortexa7hf_neon_vfpv4 conflicts with file from package nettle-dev-3.3-r0.aarch64
  file /usr/include/nettle/nettle-stdint.h from install of lib32-nettle-dev-3.3-r0.cortexa7hf_neon_vfpv4 conflicts with file from package nettle-dev-3.3-r0.aarch64
```

What is the best way to exclude 32-bit versions of libraries(recipes) when doing `-c populate_sdk` without excluding them entirely from the production image?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove target packages from the toolchain by removing them from the TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK variable and host packages by removing them from the TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK.

For example to remove the target package "curl-dev" from your sdk you have to add the following in your image recipe:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_remove = "curl-dev"
```

To remove the same host package from your sdk you have to add the following in your image recipe:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_remove = "curl-dev"
```